# autenticating ldap for web applications

Tags: c#, authentication, hash, active-directory, ldap

***please take a few minutes and read my question completely***. here is my problem : 
I want to connect to LDAP server ***by C#*** for a web application, means clients connecting to the asp.net server.

*- The ldap server and application server are not the same.

**- They are not in a same domain.

I have been trying ***4 different ways*** and could not solve the problem by none of them.

1-

```
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("domain.net");

        var conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, credentials);
            conn.Bind();
```

2-

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.net/DC=domain,DC=net");
                entry.Username = "username";
                entry.Password = "password";
                System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry);
                searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
                var results = searcher.FindAll();
```

the problem with these 2 ways is that the user must have an access to the server for login and we know that there is only admin of the system who has the permission.

3-

```
   PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.net");
   var ret = pc.ValidateCredentials(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

the problem is the server must be in the domain of ldap server. we have this limitation !!

4-

https://auth0.com/blog/using-ldap-with-c-sharp/

```
public bool validateUser(string username, string password)
{
    var sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
    var digest = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)));
    var request = new CompareRequest(string.Format("uid={0},ou=users,dc=example,dc=com", username),
        "userPassword", "{SHA}" + digest);
    var response = (CompareResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
    return response.ResultCode == ResultCode.CompareTrue;
}
```

this code does not return any thing. it will be very helpful if there is a query to compare usernames and passwords. this code seems to use this way but there are different types of hash algorithms. I tried to use SHA1 and MD5, and userPassword , unicodePwd attribute. but the return is empty all the time.

is it the best solution to put both servers in a same domain? any other solution , Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 is the simplest way. If that doesn't work, nothing will. So you will have to change your configuration to make it work.

When you say:

> the user must have an access to the server for login and we know that there is only admin of the system who has the permission.

What do you mean? Are you explicitly denying login rights to the domain controllers? Are there network issues between the computer this is running on and the domain controller (can you hit port 389 on the domain controller(s))?

*Update:* `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` just does an LDAP bind in behind - it uses `LdapConnection`. You can see the [source code here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs). The probable reason why `ValidateCredentials` is working on a domain machine and not otherwise is because it uses Kerberos authentication by default, which will only work from a domain computer.

The same is true with `LdapConnection`. So try setting the authentication mode. For example, try `Basic`

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("domain.net");

var conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, credentials, AuthType.Basic);
conn.Bind();
```

Or [look at the available values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.authtype(v=vs.110).aspx) and try what works.

Comment: ok thanks, look consider the application is on the server A and the ldap database is on the server B. for example, just the admin can login with his active directory's user pass to ldap. I can just login by my PC not any other PC. So when I want to login as a client I do not have access to ldap through web application. If I use method number 3, we do not need to have login access but the server A must be in the domain of server B, please let me know if my explanation is not cleared yet ,

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think might be the problem.

Comment: Great, almost done! but we have just one person here he cannot login to system with any type of authentication. Actually he only able to login with his PC and without an authentication type parameter, !! is it possible that for some users the authentication type be different from other employees? is there any solution? because at run time I do not know the type of authentication for every user, and they might not have access to login on other PCs. Thanks you very much

Comment: You could put the `Bind()` in a `try`/`catch` block and retest with a different method. Retest with all methods you know might work.